# displaying inline block or positioning horizontally instead of vertically

Tags: html, css

When trying to float elements or display inline they vanish. Not sure why this is. those properties seem pretty straight forward. Any input would be great

```css
body {
  background-color: grey;
}

.divison1 {
  background-color:blue;
  min-width: 100px;
  min-height: 100px;
}
.division2 {
 background-color: green;
 max-width: 100px;
 min-height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
<head>
  <title> Practice with divs!</title>
  <link href = "style.css" type = "text/css" rel = "stylesheet"/>
</head>
<body>
<div class = "divison1"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change max-height to min-height

the height of your div is 0 because its empty

```css
body {
  background-color: grey;
}

.divison1 {
  background-color:blue;
  min-width: 100px;
  min-height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
<head>
  <title> Practice with divs!</title>
  <link href = "style.css" type = "text/css" rel = "stylesheet"/>
</head>
<body>
<div class = "divison1"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you happen to tell me when I try to float these 2 divisions or display them inline one of them or both of them just vanish?

Comment: float won't make them vanish but inline will unless they have some content

Answer (score 0):

change `max-height` as `min-height`. `max-height` sets only the maximum height of the div to be 100px but here u need to set `min-height` to get some content into the div

```css
body {
  background-color: grey;
}

.divison1 {
  background-color:blue;
  min-width: 100px;
  min-height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
<head>
  <title> Practice with divs!</title>
  <link href = "style.css" type = "text/css" rel = "stylesheet"/>
</head>
<body>
<div class = "divison1"></div>
</body>
</html>
```